# Is there a DbSet<TEntity>.Local equivalent in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need an

```
ObservableCollection<TEntity>
```

in EF7,

```
DbSet<TEntity>.Local
```

doesn't seem to exist;

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current version of EntityFramework (RC1-final) has no DbSet.Local feature. But! You can achieve something similar with current extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<TEntity> GetLocal<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var context = set.GetService<DbContext>();
        var data = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Select(e => e.Entity);
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>(data);

        collection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                context.AddRange(e.NewItems.Cast<TEntity>());
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                context.RemoveRange(e.OldItems.Cast<TEntity>());
            }
        };

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Note: it won't refresh the list if you query for more data. It will sync changes to the list back into the change tracker though.