# WPF Automatic binding when an EF's entity values change

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework and I'm trying to learn it.

I was trying to modify an exercise found on the official documentation: I would like to have a list of fathers and a list of sons. Every son must have a father selected from a combobox menu.

Now I can do that but, if I add a father, I don't see it in the father list nor in the combobox. If I add a son I don't see the son in the son's list.

If I close and reopen the program I correctly see fathers and sons previously added.

How I can automatically upgrade data in combobox and in the listview?

I don't like to call a function to refresh, I would like to automatically make the refresh when changing something in the database.

My project is made of 3 files:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EF7Fam.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EF7Fam"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Page_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="550">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Width="263" Margin="3 0 3 0">
                <TextBox Name="NewFT"></TextBox>
                <Button Click="Add_Click">Add</Button>
                <ListView Name="Fathers">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="263" Margin="3 0 3 0">
                <TextBox Name="NewSN"></TextBox>
                <ComboBox Name="FT" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="FTId"/>
                <Button Click="Add_SN_Click">Add</Button>
                <ListView Name="Sons">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace EF7Fam
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using (var db = new Family())
            {
                db.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var db = new Family())
            {
                Fathers.ItemsSource = db.Fathers.ToList();
                Sons.ItemsSource = db.Sons.ToList();
                FT.ItemsSource = db.Fathers.ToList();
            }
        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var db = new Family())
            {
                var ft = new Father { Name = NewFT.Text };
                db.Fathers.Add(ft);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void Add_SN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            using (var db = new Family())
            {
                var sn = new Son { Name = NewSN.Text, FTId = Int32.Parse(FT.SelectedValue.ToString()) };
                db.Sons.Add(sn);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace EF7Fam
{

    public class Family : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Father> Fathers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Son> Sons { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename=Family.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Father>()
                .Property(b => b.Name)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }

    public class Father : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [Key]
        public int FTId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Son> Sons { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public class Son : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [Key]
        public int SNId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int FTId { get; set; }
        public Father Father { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I looked many times on this site and in the Web, but without finding a solution.

I will be very grateful if someone can help me to let me know what I doing wrong,

Thanks,
bye,

Enrico

Answer (score 3):

To bound your controls to the `DbSets` you need to do this:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        using (var db = new Family())
        {
            db.Fathers.Load();
            Fathers.ItemsSource = db.Fathers.Local;
            db.Sons.Load();
            Sons.ItemsSource = db.Sons.Local;
            FT.ItemsSource = db.Fathers.Local;
        }
}
```

Calling `Load` method you are going to load the existing objects into memory and `DbSet<TEntity>.Local` property will give you an `ObservableCollection<TEntity>` that contains all `Unchanged`, `Modified` and `Added` objects that are currently tracked by the `DbContext` for the given `DbSet`. Adding or Removing from the `ObservableCollection` will also perform the corresponding `Add`/`Remove` on the `DbSet`.

This way if you need to save changes after perform all the operations that you need in your view, you can define a command or override the click event of a button in your view and call the `SaveChanges` method of your context:

```
  private void SaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  {
        using (var db = new Family())
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
  }
```

### Update

Now I saw that you are using EF7, well the true is I'm not aware about all the changes in this version, but I can tell you that there are a lot, maybe this property is not still implemented. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819159/is-there-a-dbsettentity-local-equivalent-in-entity-framework-7) asking about that and is not answered yet.

Digging more in documentation I think I found a [solution](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html) but the true is I don't like it, but it could work until the `Load` property shows up. According to the EF documentation you can do this:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        using (var db = new Family())
        {
            var ft = new Father { Name = NewFT.Text };
            db.Fathers.Add(ft);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Fathers.ItemsSource = db.Fathers.ToList();
        }
 }
```

If I find a better solution I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! But I have a problem with this code: Visual Studio say that "DbSet<Father> does not contains a definition for and no extension method 'Local' accepting a first argument of type DbSet<Father> could be found."

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, this is not the best solution but it works! I think i will try your first solution with EF6! Thank you, bye, Enrico

Comment: You're welcome :) I think is a wise choice change to EF6 until the final version of EF 7 be released